# Access file object from ondata Handler

Tags: filepond

Is it possible to access the current file object of the input field in the ondata handler in order to send file-specific data as POST? I would like to send the lastModfiedDate of the uploaded file. At the moment, I send the data of all files with each request and then try to assign it via the file name:

```
var addedFiles = [];
[...]

ondata: (formData) => {
  for(var i = 0; i < addedFiles.length; i++) {
    formData.append('filename['+i+']', addedFiles[i].name);
    formData.append('lastModified['+i+']', addedFiles[i].lastModified);
  }
  return formData;
}

$('#myFileInput').on('FilePond:addfile', function (e) {
  addedFiles.push(e.detail.file.file);
});
```